# VM Ware Fusion 11 show black screen on Windows 10 VM

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-fusion

I'm on a Mac Catalina, using Professional Version 11.5.1 (15018442)

Lately, I can't open my `Windows 10` VM

I kept seeing

[image]

[image]

I have other VMs, Kali seems to load fine.

[image: VM]

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it solve your problem

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wro7O87ZiyE

Comment: I looked at that video. My Screen Recording doesn't have the (+) option like he is. Also, Windows 10 seems to be the only OS that's NOT working. The rest of the VM seems working.

Comment: Do you have a backup of the Windows 10 machine (since the other machines are working). A trick that sometimes work is as follows:  Make a new Virtual Machine folder and copy the Windows 10 machine (NOT move) to the new folder. So everything is intact at this point. Make a new VM pointing to the newly created folder and try opening the Windows 10 machine from the new folder.

Comment: Try this help [link](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-Client-for-Linux/4.5/com.vmware.horizon-client.linux-45.doc/GUID-75F6046C-D43A-4264-80AC-B150524CEC71.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I unchecked, and checked again, and also reboot my Mac

[image]

## Windows 10 loading.

[image]